# Not an Answer -- Did something change?

Tags: support, bug, flagging, review

Did something change recently in how Not an Answer flags are processed?

I am now getting a yellow circle with a 2:

[image]

But when I click, it doesn't show anything to review in the main part of the page.  Over on the right hand side, it says "2 x Not An Answer"--and given that I just flagged two non-answers, that seems less than coincidental:

[image]

I have never noticed this behavior until yesterday.

---

If this is an intentional change of the nature I infer, it should not show the action icon to people who cannot act.

Comment: Even if we understand why this happens, I still think it's a bug - it really shouldn't imply you have work to do when you don't.

Answer (score 3):

Ordinarily you would in fact see flagged posts and have the opportunity to flag, disagree, or (in the case of a question) vote to close.

I can verify this on Stack Overflow, where I have the reputation but am not a moderator.

My guess is that *your* flags don't show up in *your* view, precisely because you cannot act on them. The number icon, I'm also guessing, is cached globally for the entire site and probably not calculated per-user, since the likelihood of there being any noticeable discrepancy is very small, especially on a higher-traffic site.

I'm pretty sure that the screen itself has always been available to users with 10k or more reputation; if something has been added or changed recently, it's probably just the notification itself.

Comment: This is indeed the case: If something didn't change, only moderators can act on their own flags; other users cannot act on them, since the assumption is that the user who flagged a post think the flag is helpful.